# image from ajax request loads in codepen but not local environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, weather

I'm trying to use a weather api for a basic website and I'd like to use the icons too. The request works in both environments, but in my local environment I get an error for the icon

> GET file://cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I thought it was related to https but probably not since it's only the image that won't load.

```
const key = 'b7e1e81e6228412cbfe203819180104';

const url = `https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=${key}&q=auto:ip`

const main = document.getElementById('main');

$.getJSON( url, function(json) {
  const loc = json.location;
  const cur = json.current;
  const condition = {text: cur.condition.text, icon: cur.condition.icon}

  main.innerHTML = `<img src = ${condition.icon}><div>${condition.text}</div>`
}
```

so `${cur.condition.text}` will display "partly cloudy" but the icon does not display. Any advice?

update: seems to be working fine with live-server.

Comment: Your img syntax is wrong, there shouldn't be spaces around the `=` and the value should be surrounded by `"`. What is the value of `condition.icon`? It looks like it is attempting to get a `File` and not a `URL`.

Comment: thanks for the heads up about the spaces but I can't put quotes around the variables because then they'll be read as string literals. I don't think that's the problem though, since condition.text is working fine. The value of condition.icon is http://cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png

Comment: Please share your HTML code

Comment: Are you testing your files locally, so the URL start with `file:`?

Comment: they are not my files I am pulling them from a json file generated from a weather api. I switched to live server and it's working now. I'm still curious as to why so I'll leave the question open. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcone, Chek my updated answer also

Comment: _"they are not my files"_ - the HTML document that contains this JS code is though, and the error message only leaves on conclusion, that your "local environment" is not a proper setup with a web server and testing via `http(s)://`, but by simply opening the document in the browser from the local file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because the Cross-Origin Request Policy (CORS) may not allow it. Please make sure that you are allowed to access those resources.

https://enable-cors.org/ to read up more about CORS.

Secondly,

```
<img src = ${condition.icon}>
```

should be

```
<img src="${condition.icon}">
```

You are forgetting the quotation marks.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp - Read more on image tags.

Additionally use the code below:

Also add `http:` to image `src` like `<img src=http:${condition.icon}>`.

```
    const key = 'b7e1e81e6228412cbfe203819180104';

    const url = `https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=${key}&q=auto:ip`

    const main = document.getElementById('main');

    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
          const loc = json.location;
          const cur = json.current;
          const condition = {
            text: cur.condition.text,
            icon: cur.condition.icon
          }

          main.innerHTML = `<img src="http:${condition.icon}"><div>${condition.text}</div>`
        })
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: That's what I thought but then it doesn't explain why the exact same code works on codepen.com and the only part that doesn't work locally is the image. And I didn't use quotations because those are es6 template literals.

Comment: Codepen.com may be parsing the invalid HTML, but that doesn't mean you should write invalid HTML. Please read up the link I provided you and follow HTML standards to avoid errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

As icon return in JSON as protocol-relative URL (without the scheme) `//url`.

Locally it will use the `file://` protocol and that assumes the resource you’re referring to is on the local machine, But it's not.


To avoid this issue locally add `http:` or `https:`to image `src` like `<img src=http:${condition.icon}>`.

```js
const key = 'b7e1e81e6228412cbfe203819180104';

const url = `https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=${key}&q=auto:ip`

const main = document.getElementById('main');

$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
      const loc = json.location;
      const cur = json.current;
      const condition = {
        text: cur.condition.text,
        icon: cur.condition.icon
      }

      main.innerHTML = `<img src =http:${condition.icon}><div>${condition.text}</div>`
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```